# Thread Safe (CG) Version of UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext?

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, ios, cgcontext

Im trying to render PDF pages to images on a background thread, is there a thread safe way of generating an image from a pdfContext/context that doesn't not use:

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK (almost) all Core Graphics calls should be safe to use in a background thread as long you don't draw on screen and don't share resources (such as graphics contexts) among multiple threads.

Comment: does `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` not (only) work with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` which isn't thread safe though? or does it work with any CGContextRef?

Comment: or rather this: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`

Comment: Yeah, but you said you didn't want to use that function. You can use CG calls to draw into a bitmap context and then create a `CGImage` from it. Btw, Apple made some `UIGraphics...` calls thread safe in iOS 4.0, you might want to review that.

Comment: Where would i find documentation like that? I had a look round the dev portal but i couldn't find anything specific, unless it was just a footnote on individual function documentation?

Comment: From "What's New in iOS 4.0": "Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically: The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads. String and image drawing is now thread-safe. Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do." (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29) The "What's New" document released with each new release is a must to read and memorize IMO.